# Is it possible in Android Studio to build a native module with .so as output

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have several c++ projects which I currently build using Android.mk files and ndk-build. Since this is not really great to debug I want to include this c++ projects as modules inside my android studio project. This android studio project is currently an android java library which uses the .so from the ndk-build.

I got debugging to work by creating a new android library module and importing the c++ code, setting header and library paths. This module looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 4
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = 'module_name'
        toolchain = 'gcc'
        stl "gnustl_static"
        ldFlags.addAll(["-L/LIB_PATH"])
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log", "whatever_lib"])


        cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11',
                         "-I" + "/SEARCH_PATHS"])

    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            java.source.srcDirs += []
            res.source.srcDirs += []
            assets.source.srcDirs += []
            jniLibs.source.srcDirs += []
            jni.source{
                srcDirs += [
                        NATIVE_PROJECT_PATH + "include/",
                        NATIVE_PROJECT_PATH + "src/",

                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but i get the .so in module/build/output/aar/libname_release.aar/lib/abi/lib.so which is not a good spot since i would need the .so directly without unzipping the aar.

Is there any possible way to let this module only create the .so at a given path and have another module build and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I find a way shortly after asking.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies

Instead of "apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'" you can use "apply plugin: 'com.android.model.native'" and in the module having the dependency you can use:

```
sources {
    main {
        jni {
            dependencies {
                project ":dependency_module"
            }
        }
    }
}
```