# How to include c/cpp header files inside aar？

Tags: c++, header, aar

Android `.aar` usually only contain `*.jar`, `*.so` and asset related resources.

How to include `*.so` related header files inside `.aar`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AndroidNativeBundle](https://github.com/howardpang/androidNativeBundle) plugin.

- Edit your root build.gradle file, add classpath 'io.github.howardpang:androidNativeBundle:1.1.1' to the file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        //Add androidNativeBundle dependency
        classpath "io.github.howardpang:androidNativeBundle:1.1.1"
    }
}
```

- Apply plugin to your lib, add following line to your lib build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'com.ydq.android.gradle.native-aar.export'
}
```

- Specify header path that you want to export, add following code segment to your lib build.gradle;

```
nativeBundleExport {
    headerDir = "${project.projectDir}/native/export/header/path"
}
```